# Service broker error: Internal Server Error when trying to unbind service

Tags: swisscomdev

When I try to unbind my app from mariadb service I get:

Unexpected Response

Response code: 502

CC code:       0

CC error code:

Request ID:    48c77bfe-4c22-4e56-4d62-34fc113a10d4::166ca652-62ac-4829-8c37-5009c1796426

```
Description:   {
  "description": "Service instance gatewayDB: Service broker error: Internal Server Error",
  "error_code": "CF-ServiceBrokerBadResponse",
  "code": 10001,
  "http": {
    "uri": "http://open-service-broker.service.consul:8080/cf-broker/v2/service_instances/{service_instance}/service_bindings/{service-binding}",
    "method": "DELETE",
    "status": 500
  }
}
```

I have all the rights for the organization/space.

EDIT:
When I try to restage the app with exiting mariadb service instance, I get Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Could not connect: Access denied for user '{username}'@'{host}' (using password: YES)

Maybe environment variables are causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We apologize for any inconvenience this issue caused to you. We fixed it and now the unbinding works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue on the provider's side, please open a support ticket with them.